# Single Instance of Application Service in DDD Approach

Tags: design-patterns, singleton, domain-driven-design, stateless

As I have learned about **Application Service** layer, it must be *stateless* i.e. it shouldn't store any dynamic data in properties or fields. So different instances of Application Service would do almost the same thing. So does it mean we may implement it as a *static* class or using *singleton* pattern?

Answer (score 2):

A stateless service should have all the state passed in when calling the relevant method.  The application service itself may have other dependencies that would be injected.

Dependency inversion is your friend here and I would not recommend a `static` class.  Rather use some dependency injection with a singleton pattern and if you are so inclined I'd suggest using a dependency injection container such as Castle Windsor, StructureMap, Autofac, Ninject, Unity, or SimpleInjector --- I'm sure there are others.

If you do run into singletons that require state I have a short [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JMxQlgOH7cg) on that.

Answer (score 2):

I am quoting from [this pluralsight course by Julie Lerman & Steve Smith](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/domain-driven-design-fundamentals/table-of-contents).

> Domain services should be stateless, though they may have side
>   effects. What this means is we should always be able to simply create
>   a new instance of a service to perform an operation, rather than
>   having to rely on any previous history that might've occurred within a
>   particular service instance. But of course, the result of calling a
>   method on a service might result in changes to the state of the system
>   itself.

Same concept applies to Application Services. Note that *Stateless* does NOT mean `static`. As an example, we can have an `EmailSenderService`... the service sends an email and potentially returns *Success/Failure*. Later if we want to send another email, we instantiate a new `EmailSenderService` to send the email... we do not rely on the fact that the previous email was sent successfully or not.

Also as Eben has pointed out, services are often injected in the consumers, `static` types cannot be injected and that's one good reason for not using `static` services.

This is a [really good article by Jimmy Bogard about services in DDD](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/08/21/services-in-domain-driven-design/).

I also recommend checking this [project by Dino Esposito](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=naa4e#IBuyStuff-dm/src/Site/IBuyStuff.Application/), as a sample DDD project.

Answer (score 1):

Statelesness is a somewhat loaded concept that people use to mean different things in a service.

- At a minimum, it shouldn't remember anything about a request between two invocations.
- By an extended definition, it should [minimize the amount of state information](http://www.ebizq.net/blogs/service_oriented/2009/02/evolution_of_principles_of_service_orientation_service_statelessness_part_6.php) it manages.

Whatever the case, neither static nor singleton are necessary or sufficient to make a stateless service. A static service can perfectly be stateful, as can a singleton one.

In other words, all properties of statelessness can hold true even if you use a non-static, non-singleton class. Which should probably be should be your default mode, unless you have very good other reasons to use these approaches.